# spring log4j log specific soap message

Tags: java, spring, soap, log4j

I have this `logging.level.org.springframework.ws.server.MessageTracing.received=TRACE` setting in my application.properties so it prints out whatever soap messages my application receives.

Just want to know if it's possible to only log a specific type of message. for example if my endpoints can process `MessageClassA` and `MessageClassB`, can I only log `MessageClassA` received?